# Why ScannerObj.hasNextInt() require to enter input?

Tags: java

Hi I am really confused!
From the below code, you can see that the obj.NextInt() asks for input and also
obj.hasNextInt() requires to enter input.

```
Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
bool x = obj.hasNextInt();
out.print(x);
```

it requires to enter an input. why?

Comment: Because it can't predict what you may type in.

Answer (score 1):

```
hasNextInt()
```

Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value   in the default radix using the nextInt() method.

```
nextInt()
```

Scans the next token of the input as an int.

JavaDoc for [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `hasNextInt()` method returns true if the next set of characters in the input stream can be read in as an int. If they can't be read as an int, or if the end of the file has been reached, then it returns false.